# Presentation Deck Xamarin

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I am trying to make a presentation deck like "IF by IFTTT" application. UIPageViewController swipe pages one by one, so I am already out of options.
What I want to do is multiple pages/images in one swipe or something like that.

[image]

Comment: "Please enlighten me" isn't  really a valid question.

Comment: UIScrollView is your friend.